# IndentationError in Python

Tags: python, user-interface, button, indentation

I wrote the following program but not sure what is the problem with it, it is giving :

```
File "Button_2.py", line 9
""" Initialise the Frame. """
                            ^
  IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

This is an image of my code:

[image]

What is going on here?

Answer (score 5):

The indentation on your docstring in `__init__` is off (It needs to move 1 indentation level to the right) ... The indentation on `root.mainloop()` is also off.

Comment: A couple of the comments look odd as well and are confusing to read

Comment: I still do not get this indentation thing in python, the code seems right but still. You mean I need to add one space to the right?

Comment: @user1581917 -- No, 1 indentation level.  the docstring (`""" .... """`) should have the same number of spaces in front of it as the next line.

Comment: How should I turn on the indentation on 'root.mainloop()' @mgilson

Comment: Oh i got it now... It works what about the root.mainloop() indentation?

Comment: @user1581917 -- That should have 0 spaces in front of it to line up with `app = Application(root)`

Answer (score 2):

Your indentation is wrong on line 9 aka the docstring should be indented one level to the right like this:

```
def __init__(self, master):
    """ Initialise the Frame. """
    Frame.__init__(self, master)
```

The reason for this is because Python uses indentation to tell the interpreter to which class, function, or structure (like a loop or if..else statement) a block of code belongs to. It is the equivalent of curly braces in Java, which you use to specify classes, methods, or other flow control parts of your program. You can read up more here: http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/block_indentation.hawk

P.S. The root.mainLoop() should be, in turn, de-indented back to the left. This is because it is part of the main program, whose indentation level is 0.

Answer (score 1):

You should indent the docstring as follows:

```
def __init__(self, master):
    """ Initialise the Frame. """
    Frame.__init__(self, master)
```

Answer (score 0):

Line 5 should be indented 1 more level, align with line 6.